# Get the _updatedAt field in Azure Mobile Services

Tags: azure, xna, json.net

I am using Azure Mobile Services to store and retrieve highscores for my XNA game. Azure provides a native _updatedAt column, but somehow I am not able to retrieve it.

This is my current code:

```
public class ScoreItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "score")]
    public int Score { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_updatedAt")]
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the mistake, system columns start with a double underscore. So the correct code would be

public class ScoreItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user_name")]
public string Name { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "score")]
public int Score { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "__updatedAt")]
public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
```

}